# How to set properly a recycler view in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I wonder how am I supposed to set properly my Recycler View in my fragment, the dashboardViewModel "observe" the text field but I have not find how to observe the Recycler View, so I just binded it and set an Adapter, but I think I am in the wrong way.

```java
// My Dashboard fragment :
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textDashboard;
        dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
        DummyDatas dummyDatas = new DummyDatas();
        ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(dummyDatas.getProducts());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

        return root;

// My Dash board view Model

    public DashboardViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mProducts = new MutableLiveData<>();

        DummyDatas dummyDatas = new DummyDatas();
        List<Product> products = dummyDatas.getProducts();

        double totalBasketPrice = 0.0;

        for (Product product : products){
            System.out.println(product.getPriceAtUnit());
            totalBasketPrice = totalBasketPrice + product.getPriceAtUnit();
        }

        mProducts.setValue(products);

        mText.setValue("Price :" + totalBasketPrice);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Product>> getProducts() {
        return mProducts;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking on how to use observer to update RecyclerView? If yes edit the title saying "How to update RecyclerView on LiveData changes?".

Cause your title is misleading, it means "How do i add RecyclerView in Fragment" which you did already in your layout and also set an adapter to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the RecyclerView data using the adapter inside the `LiveData.observe()` function.

```java
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    final TextView textView = binding.textDashboard;
    dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
    DummyDatas dummyDatas = new DummyDatas();
    final ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(dummyDatas.getProducts());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

    // observe products and update data using adapter's data functions
    // either replace the whole list, or use DiffUtil
    dashboardViewModel.getProducts().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), products -> {
        productAdapter.setProducts(products);
        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I did it. Might be helpful for you!

First I created sample layout for recyclerView

sample_recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="165dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/foodImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/food0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFood"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
                android:background="@color/pinkish"
                android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/food_over"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The add this layout in the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecylerviewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/sample_recylerview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then i created model class for the data i required to be in the sample layout.

FoodModel.java

```
public class FoodModel {

    //I have provided images in the drawable that's why taking image as int 
    // otherwise we have to to with the String when we are taking images from
    // database like firease
    int image;
    String foodText;

    //constructor
    public FoodModel(int image, String foodText) {
        this.image = image;
        this.foodText = foodText;
    }

    //getter and setter
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getFoodText() {
        return foodText;
    }

    public void setFoodText(String foodText) {
        this.foodText = foodText;
    }
}
```

Now before creating the Adapter class, we will create another class for clickeListeners for each item of the recyclerview. you can skip it if you don't need it now, but I think you will definitely need it in the future.

RecyclerItemClickListener.java

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener nListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void OnLongItemClick(View view, int position);

    }

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    //constructor

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        nListener = onItemClickListener;

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event){
                return true;
            }

            public void onLongItemClick (MotionEvent event) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());

                if(child != null && nListener !=null){
                    nListener.OnLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {

        View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView != null && nListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            nListener.onItemClick(childView, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Now we will create an adapter class

FoodAdapter.Java

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<FoodModel> list;
    Context context;

    //constructor
    public FoodAdapter(ArrayList<FoodModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //we will inflate the layout in this method
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_recylerview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // we will set the values of image and text here, in this method
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        FoodModel foodModel = list.get(position);

        //setting data
        holder.fImage.setImageResource(foodModel.getImage());
        holder.fText.setText(foodModel.getFoodText());

        //on item click Listener
       switch (holder.getAdapterPosition()){

           // we can add separate on click listeners on each items(case) as well.
           //but, here we have implemented same code on all items.
           case 0:
           case 1:
           case 2:
           case 3:
           case 4:
           case 5:
           case 6:
           case 7:
           case 8:
           case 9:
// This part we have done in MainActivity.java so I have commented it here. just 
  // to know how we can do it in adapter. 
//               holder.fImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                   @Override
//                   public void onClick(View v) {
//                       Toast.makeText(context, "Image " +(holder.getAdapterPosition()+1)+" is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                   }
//               });
//               holder.fText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                   @Override
//                   public void onClick(View v) {
//                       Toast.makeText(context, "Text "+(holder.getAdapterPosition()+1)+" is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                   }
//               });

               //long clicked
               holder.fImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                       if (v.isLongClickable()){
                           Toast.makeText(context, "Image "+(holder.getAdapterPosition()+1)+" Clicked Long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                       return false;
                   }
               });

               holder.fText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                       if (v.isLongClickable()){
                           Toast.makeText(context, "Text "+(holder.getAdapterPosition()+1)+" Clicked Long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                       return false;
                   }
               });


               break;
           default:

               break;
       }

    }

    // size of items or size of recyclerView
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    //view holder class
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView fImage;
        TextView fText;

        //constructor
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            fImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodImage);
            fText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFood);

        }
    }
}
```

Here's Main Activity

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecylerviewId);
    
            //creating arraylist to store data to show the data
    
            ArrayList<FoodModel> fList = new ArrayList<>();
    
            //data insertion in recycelrView using model class
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food0, "Zinger Burger"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food1, "Beef Burger Special"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food2, "Chicken Karahi"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food3, "Beef Pulao"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food4, "Zinger Roll"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food5, "Roll Paratha"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food6, "Naan Khatai"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food7, "Special Rogni Naan"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food8, "Chicken Biryani"));
            fList.add(new FoodModel(R.drawable.food9, "Cold Drinks"));
    
            //setting adapter
            FoodAdapter adapter = new FoodAdapter(fList, this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
//different layouts for you to try
            //setting Linear Layout Manager (vertical)
    //        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    
            //setting Linear Layout Manager (Horizontal)
            //here false is for sweeping items from right and true is for left.
    //        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    //        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    
            // setting grid layout Manager
    //        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    //        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    
            // staggered layout Manager
    
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    
            // On Item Touch Listener on recyclerView
    
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                    this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    
                    switch (position){
    
                        case 0:
//created scroll activity to show here on click of the item 
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollingActivityFood.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Second Item is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Third Item is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        default:
    
                            break;
                    }
                }
    
                // long item is not working, but, item Long Clicked set in Adapter is working fine.
                @Override
                public void OnLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
    
                    switch (position){
    
                        case 0:
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item is Clicked Long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
    
                        default:
    
                    }
    
                }
            }
            ));
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP didn't ask on how to use recyclerview, he asked how to use LiveData observer for recyclerview, which you didn't mention.